# How can I add WebView into a Widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-webview

I'm trying to make a recording Widget where the user interface would be loaded from HTML page in WebView. Is this possible? I've been trying to load url into Widget but I get all sorts of errors and my program crashes. I'm new to Android development and don't really know how this stuff works yet.

This is my Widget provider class:

```
public class RecordAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
WebView webview;
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

}
}
```

I think I'll have to load the WebView in some way, normally I do it with this:

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

But it doesn't work here, I think findViewById is from Activity?

Answer (score 17):

You can't use WebView within widget layout, sorry. As [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) states the only supported views are:

- AnalogClock
- Button
- Chronometer
- ImageButton
- ImageView
- ProgressBar
- TextView

Honeycomb Added more supported views:

- ViewFlipper
- ListView
- GridView
- StackView
- AdapterViewFlipper

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible to use webviews in a widget. Only more static things like lists and pictures can be used.