# Can a HTML5 app for android have a widget on the home screen?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm looking into build a app in HTML5 and needed to know is it possible to have the app work outside of the phonegap/titanium (or whatever platform) wrapper (if thats the correct term?) to have a widget on the home screen? or make an timed alert?

example, if I made an app to show game scores, can i make the widget show the current game or something of that nature? then alert the user when the game is over?

Not sure if HTML5 can handle this or if it needes to be native.

For what its worth im using html5 due to me doing front end development.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No. You can have HTML5 pages as widgets on the home screen, but you'd have to determine a way to pass info between the pages. To make an HTML5 widget, one would have to make an WebView widget (In Java), and point it at the HTML page.

Comment: Im guessing that goes outside of the html5 aspect but i found this aswell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402598/how-can-i-add-webview-into-a-widget